# Python: Aggregate & averaging rows based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the average travel time for an **Average Work Day** = 5 days and an **Average Weekend day** = 2 days.'

I'm trying to aggregate and find the average for the veh-time for all the rows with the same 'Time' and same 'Day_type'. Because 'Time' values include seconds as well, I'm finding some trouble matching all the veh-times that belong to the same 'Time'.

My dataframe is set-up in the following way:

```
  veh-time distance Date    Time        Day_of_week Day_type
0   72  379.0   2018-10-18  22:15:21    Thursday    Weekday
1   72  379.0   2018-10-18  22:30:21    Friday      Weekend
2   72  379.0   2018-10-18  22:45:22    Saturday    Weekend
3   72  379.0   2018-10-18  23:00:20    Sunday      Weekday
4   72  379.0   2018-10-18  23:15:21    Monday      Weekday
5   72  379.0   2018-10-18  23:15:21    Tuesday     Weekday
6   72  379.0   2018-10-18  23:15:21    Wednesday   Weekday
7   72  379.0   2018-10-18  22:15:21    Thursday    Weekday
8   72  379.0   2018-10-18  22:30:21    Friday      Weekend
9   72  379.0   2018-10-18  22:45:22    Saturday    Weekend
10  72  379.0   2018-10-18  23:00:20    Sunday      Weekday
11  72  379.0   2018-10-18  23:15:21    Monday      Weekday
12  72  379.0   2018-10-18  23:15:21    Tuesday     Weekday
13  72  379.0   2018-10-18  23:15:21    Wednesday   Weekday
```

I'm guessing the process would look like this:

**STEP 1:**
split the 'Time' column so it'll **only** show HH:MM. Maybe use `regex` or `str.split()`

**STEP 2:**
group all veh-time rows that with matching 'Time' AND 'Day_type' - e.g. all rows with time 22:15 and day type Weekday

**STEP 3:** 
add a new column: 'avg_vt' after finding the average for the grouped rows in step 2. 
avg_vt = veh-time + veh-time etc. / # of Day_type instance identified

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column filled by aggregate values, for extract `HH:MM` is used [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n=1` for split from right side with only first `:` or convert to datetimes and then to `HH:MM` string with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['avg_vt'] = df.groupby([df['Time'].str.rsplit(':', n=1).str[0], 
                          'Day_type'])['veh-time'].transform('mean')
```

Alternative:

```
df['avg_vt'] = df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M'), 
                          'Day_type'])['veh-time'].transform('mean')
```

---

```
print (df)
    veh-time  distance        Date      Time Day_of_week Day_type  avg_vt
0         72     379.0  2018-10-18  22:15:21    Thursday  Weekday      72
1         72     379.0  2018-10-18  22:30:21      Friday  Weekend      72
2         72     379.0  2018-10-18  22:45:22    Saturday  Weekend      72
3         72     379.0  2018-10-18  23:00:20      Sunday  Weekday      72
4         72     379.0  2018-10-18  23:15:21      Monday  Weekday      72
5         72     379.0  2018-10-18  23:15:21     Tuesday  Weekday      72
6         72     379.0  2018-10-18  23:15:21   Wednesday  Weekday      72
7         72     379.0  2018-10-18  22:15:21    Thursday  Weekday      72
8         72     379.0  2018-10-18  22:30:21      Friday  Weekend      72
9         72     379.0  2018-10-18  22:45:22    Saturday  Weekend      72
10        72     379.0  2018-10-18  23:00:20      Sunday  Weekday      72
11        72     379.0  2018-10-18  23:15:21      Monday  Weekday      72
12        72     379.0  2018-10-18  23:15:21     Tuesday  Weekday      72
13        72     379.0  2018-10-18  23:15:21   Wednesday  Weekday      72
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Time'].str.rsplit(':', n=1).str[0])
0    22:15
1    22:30
2    22:45
3    23:00
4    23:15
5    23:15
...
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It ties all it all in one single command. When using the second option, I get a TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime. Could this be because the 'Time' column was from a timestamp that I have split into the 'Date' and 'Time' column using temp.date & temp.time command?

Comment: @RenaldoMoon - yes, for second use `pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].astype(str)).dt.strftime('%H:%M')`

Comment: @RenaldoMoon - If you have datetime column then use `df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')`